# Change Drupal font Site-Wide?

Tags: drupal, fonts, font-face, font-family

There are a few pretty impressive font apps out there. My favourite is Font your Face (http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface). Only problem is it only allows for you to use existing sources. i.e.

- Typekit.com
- Google Font API
- KERNEST
- Font Squirrel
- Common fonts -- fonts already available in most browsers

Is there any way to add a "source" that is effectively grabbing files off the server? I want to be able to upload my own fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [@font-your-face module](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) now includes a local fonts module that does exactly what you've described here.

Answer (score 2):

We've had good luck with [webfonts](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=What_are_webfonts%3F), though we're not using any Drupal modules, just adding them to the theme using CSS.